Next.js 14 loading UI appears in an infinite scroll component with server actions
I need to stop the loading UI from showing while the data is loading from a server action so what is happening is:
User scrolls down -> infinite scroll triggers -> triggers server action -> loading ui (loading.tsx) appears -> page refreashes the whole page instead of appending data
and what I need to happen is
User scrolls down -> infinite scroll triggers -> triggers server action -> appends new data to the old ones
my code:
page.tsx:
import React from "react";
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next";
import styles from "./page.module.css";

import { screenParams } from "@/types/screenParams";

import SearchBox from "@/components/UI/searchBox";
import NoResult from "@/components/UI/noResult";
import Error from "@/components/UI/error";
import IntersectionObserver from "@/components/interface/intersectionObserver";

import handlePageMedata from "@/functions/handlePageMetadata";
import listMorePosts from "@/server/listMorePosts";

export async function generateMetadata(
    { params }: screenParams,
    parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
    return await handlePageMedata({
        parent,
        params,
        route: "propertyAll",
    });
}

async function page({ params, searchParams }: screenParams) {
    const data = await listMorePosts(null, params.lang);

    if (!data) {
        return <Error />;
    }

    if (!data.items || data.items.length === 0) {
        return <NoResult />;
    }

    const firstNextToken = data.nextToken;
    return (
        <main className={`${styles.main}`}>
            <SearchBox params={searchParams} />
            <div className={`${styles.wrapper}`}>{data.items}</div>
            <IntersectionObserver
                nextToken={firstNextToken}
                lang={params.lang}
                type={"posts"}
                wrapperClass={`${styles.wrapper}`}
            />
        </main>
    );
}

export default page;

IntersectionObserver.tsx(fetches data and appends to list)
"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";

import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

import ButtonOne from "@/components/buttons/buttonOne";
import listMorePosts from "@/server/listMorePosts";
import listMoreSellers from "@/server/listMoreSellers";

import type { languages } from "@/types/screenParams";

type props = {
    nextToken: string | null;
    lang: languages;
    type: "posts" | "sellers";
    wrapperClass?: string;
};

// TODO: finish this component
function IntersectionObserver({ nextToken: firstNextToken, lang, type, wrapperClass }: props) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState<string | null>(firstNextToken);
    const [items, setItems] = useState<React.JSX.Element[]>([]);

    const { ref, inView } = useInView({
        /* Optional options */
        threshold: 0,
    });

    async function loadMore() {
        if (loading) return;
        // if (!nextToken) return;
        console.log("loading more");
        setLoading(true);
        const results =
            type === "posts"
                ? await listMorePosts(nextToken, lang)
                : await listMoreSellers(nextToken, lang);
        if (!results) {
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        if (results.items && results.items.length > 0) {
            setItems([...items, ...results.items]);
        }
        setNextToken(results.nextToken);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inView", inView);
        if (inView) {
            loadMore();
        }
    }, [inView]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`${styles.wrapper} ${wrapperClass}`}>{items}</div>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <ButtonOne onClick={loadMore} isLoading={loading} text="Load More" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default IntersectionObserver;

ListMorePosts.tsx(Server action):
"use server";
import React from "react";

import PropertyBox from "@/components/UI/propertyBox";
import makePostRequest, { makeRequestInput } from "@/functions/makePostRequest";
import type { listPosts } from "@/types/api";

import { languages } from "@/types/screenParams";

import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "@/amplifyconfiguration.json";

Amplify.configure(config);

async function listMorePosts(
    nextToken: string | null,
    lang: languages
): Promise<{ items: React.JSX.Element[] | undefined; nextToken: string | null } | undefined> {
    const requestInput: makeRequestInput = {
       // api info here 
};

    function listItemsFunction(list: listPosts) {
        const items = list?.items;
        if (!items) return;
        return items.map((item) => <PropertyBox key={item.id} post={item} lang={lang} />);
    }

    async function makeRequest(nextToken: string | null) {
        return (await makePostRequest({
            ...requestInput,
            body: {
                nextToken: nextToken,
            },
        })) as listPosts;
    }

    const data = await makeRequest(nextToken);

    if (!data || !data.items || data.items.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    return { items: listItemsFunction(data), nextToken: data.nextToken };
}

export default listMorePosts;

PropertyBox(Item):
import React from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";

import Image from "@/components/UI/image";

import type { Post as propertyPost } from "@/types/graphql";
import type { languages } from "@/types/screenParams";

function PropertyBox({ post, lang }: { post: propertyPost; lang: languages }) {
    return (
        <Link
            className={`${styles.itemBox}`}
            href={`/${lang}/property?id=${post.id}`}
            prefetch={false}
        >
            <div className={`${styles.image}`}>
                <Image photo={post.mainImage} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <p>{post.description}</p>
                <p>Price: {post.price}</p>
            </div>
        </Link>
    );
}

export default PropertyBox;


I tried the answer in this question but it didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78224529/nextjs-14-loading-ui-flickering-when-push-more-data-in-infinite-scroll-list-fro
